# Treat a java.lang.Iterable as a #list expression in Freemarker

Tags: java, list, freemarker, iterable

I have a java.lang.Iterable (in fact, a com.google.gson.JsonArray instance).

I would like to enumerate the items in the list using freemarker (2.3.16).

```
[#assign sports = controller.sports]
[#-- At this point, sports is bound to a com.google.gson.JsonArray instance. --]

[#list sports as sport]
  ${sport_index}
[/#list]
```

I would like to avoid having to write a custom bean and Gson deserializer just to have an explicit collection of items. Using Gson (which already deserializes the JSON string to a JsonObject for me) to then create my own DAG of objects from that JsonObject seems wasteful to me.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to work out a way of getting Freemarker to treat the java.lang.Iterable as a list. I get:

```
freemarker.template.TemplateException : Expected collection or sequence.
  controller.sports evaluated instead to freemarker.ext.beans.XMLStringModel on line 8, column 16 in sports.html.
freemarker.core.TemplateObject.invalidTypeException(line:135)
freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$Context.runLoop(line:190)
freemarker.core.Environment.visit(line:417)
freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(line:102)
freemarker.core.Environment.visit(line:210)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Explicitly looping over the iterator should work, e.g.:

```
[#list sports.iterator() as sport]
   ${sport_index}
[/#list]
```

Comment: I feel like there's been a better solution since this post and I actually used it...but can't seem to find it and figure it out so I'm using this again! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is add the result of `iterator()` on your `JsonArray` to the context.  Freemarker is smart enough to handle it from there, and you can reference it in your template like you do any other list-like variable.

Answer (score 1):

Freemarker now supports `Iterable`'s by creating your freemarker config via:

```java
configuration = new Configuration(VERSION_2_3_28);
DefaultObjectWrapper objectWrapper = new DefaultObjectWrapper(VERSION_2_3_28);
objectWrapper.setIterableSupport(true);
configuration.setObjectWrapper(objectWrapper);
```

and updating to the 2.3.28 release (I'm not exactly sure which version added this, but .23 didn't have it), then simply instantiate your `Template` passing in that configuration.

```
return new Template("somename", someReader, configuration);
```